# Generic configuration of unknown subtypes with differing getters setters

Tags: java, android, generics, design-patterns, data-binding

I would like to be able to read and write (get and set) certain fields for a bunch of related but different classes **without knowing what type of concrete class they are exactly**. All I know is that they have some types of parameters that I would like to be able to generically access and modify. And given I don't know what concrete type the class is I don't know up-front what the specific parameter types of each are either.

- I think the following approach would work, but is it good enough / what problems might it have?
- Or are there better approaches / or even established design patterns for this issue?

#### A Superclass to Allow Generic Configurability

```
public abstract class ParametrizerBase<P1, P2> {
    public P1 Param1;
    public P2 Param2;
}
```

#### Some Concrete Class with Specific Parameters It Needs

```
public class SomeConcreteClass extends ParametrizerBase<Boolean, String> {
    public SomeConcreteClass(Boolean enabled, String task){
        Param1 = enabled;
        Param2 = task;
    }
    // ... does something with the parameter data
}
```

#### Another Concrete Class with Different Types of Data

```
public class AnotherConcreteClass extends ParametrizerBase<Integer, Date> {
    public AnotherConcreteClass(Integer numberOfItems, Date when){
        Param1 = numberOfItems;
        Param2 = when;
    }
    // ... does something with the data it holds
}
```

#### Example Usage

```
    ArrayList<ParametrizerBase> list;

    public void initSomewhere() {
        SomeConcreteClass some = new SomeConcreteClass(true,"Smth");
        AnotherConcreteClass another = new AnotherConcreteClass(5, new Date());
        list = new ArrayList<ParametrizerBase>();
        list.add(some);
        list.add(another);
    }

    public void provideDataElsewhere() {
        for (ParametrizerBase concrete : list) {
            String param1Type = concrete.Param1.getClass().getName();
            if (param1Type.contains("Boolean")) {
                 Boolean value = concrete.Param1;
                 // Now could let user modify this Boolean with a checkbox 
                 // and if they do modify, then write it to concrete.Param1 = ...
                 // All without knowing what Param1 is (generic configuration)
            } else if (param1Type.contains("Integer")) {
                 Integer value = concrete.Param1;
                 // ...
            } // ...
            // Same for Param2 ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: try instanceof, rather than fetching class name string then compairing. (By the way watch out for the subclasses while using this tip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Java interface to describe the getters and setters. Have all the concrete classes implement this interface. Cast the objects to be the interface type, and call the getters and setters as needed.

Comment: 1) Im not sure I understand properly, specifically the first sentence - would "describe" mean the interface has Boolean getBoolean(), getInteger() etc? But given the concrete classes have only a **subset** of **differing** getters and setters then each concrete class would have to contain null implementations of the plethora of types that it does not actually use? (if i understood you correctly)

Comment: 2) I realize I did not mention an important extra requirement, which is that I need the concrete subclasses to take as little responsibility as possible in enabling this generic configuration - ideally they would not really do anything more than just specifying the parameters they need. This is especially important as I am providing a library, so I will not be the one implementing the concrete classes. Your solution as I understand it unfortunately requires extra boilerplate code in all the concrete classes :(

Comment: @Cel: First, you have different concrete classes all with "certain fields". Now, you are saying that they do not have "certain fields", but rather have very uncertain fields. You are welcome to try to apply techniques like the [`Property` construct from Android 4.0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Property.html). Personally, I think that this feels tpo abstract, and that a better object model will simplify things for all parties.

Comment: Thanks for the Property highlight, I found [a library that makes it available for earlier versions of Android as well](https://github.com/Tombarr/ICS-Property).....

I do agree that it is not appropriate in my case, as there is enough structure to use a more restrictive/narrow object model. Im still not sure i understood you properly though, some sample code would make it clearer, but Im happy to leave it here, too. Thanks.